# Can anyone help identify a rose?

Tags: identification, roses

Any help would be greatly appreciated. It's quite a tall rose bush. At least 7 or 8ft. I could get more pics if needed.

[image]

Comment: +1 for a lovely photo, and for a healthy plant. If I recall correctly, scent is part of ID of roses. Strong rose scent tends to tell you one class, lack of scent another. But I see this was asked nearly 2 years ago, and the forum's feed has brought it to me.

Comment: Woww...just wowww...

Answer (score 0):

Possibly a David Austin rose. Take a look at the website [here](https://www.davidaustinroses.co.uk/collections/english-rose-shrubs).

Comment: Thank you I'll have a look!